# Selenium, Python - Как нажать на кнопку?

Tags: python, selenium

помогите пожалуйста не могу нажать на объект.
я подозреваю, проблема в том что  бекграунд кнопки не дает нажать на её
[image: скрин кнопки]

[image: скрин кода html]

Если сменить название класса то бекграунд пропадает ,
[image: смена названия класса]
[image: вид кнопки после изменения класса]
но я не знаю как сменить название класса через python selenium

Answer (score 0):

нашел способ, если кому нужно

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Claim now')]").click()
```